# Trying to load tsconfig as a json object

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I am trying to load my own tsconfig as a json object. For some reason it is not working:

```
    SyntaxError: Unexpected token } in JSON at position 215
        at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

      102 | MultiService.initialize()
      103 |
    > 104 | import { default as TSCONFIG } from '../../tsconfig.json'
          | ^
```

The thing is, the path appears to be valid, but my tsconfig is only 48 lines long.

This is being run currently in jest, but the execution path in the stack is:

```
      at Runtime._loadModule (../../../../../usr/local/lib/node_modules/jest/node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:889:59)
```

and '../..' from there is '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jest/node_modules' where it is highly unlikely that some *other* tsconfig is hanging out. So this makes me think it is locating the correct tsconfig. Is there any obvious error with my approach?

#### edit

I just realized that "position 215" is not "line 215" .. I believe that must be the opening curly brace in this section in the config:

```json
    "plugins": [
      { "transform": "ts-transformer-keys/transformer" }
    ],
```

are nested object not supported?

#### test result 'Can you read that file using fs?'

added just above the offending line:

```js
console.log(fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, '../../tsconfig.json')).toString())
```

produces:

```
    {
      "compilerOptions": { 
        "outDir": "dist/bundle",
        "baseUrl": "./src",
        "paths": {
          "@blockchain/*": [ "blockchain/*" ],
          "@hyperledger/*": [ "hyperledger/*" ],
          "@lib/*": [ "lib/*" ],
        },
        "plugins": [
          { "transform": "ts-transformer-keys/transformer" }
        ],
        "module": "CommonJS",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "target": "ES2020",
        "lib": [ "ESNext" ],
        "allowJs": false,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "allowUnreachableCode": false,
        "allowUnusedLabels": false,
        "alwaysStrict": true,
        "declaration": true,
        "declarationMap": true,
        "emitBOM": false,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "importsNotUsedAsValues": "error",
        "isolatedModules": true,
        "newLine": "LF",
        "noEmitOnError": true,
        "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "noUnusedParameters": true,
        "pretty": true,
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "strict": true,
        "stripInternal": true,
        "useDefineForClassFields": true,
      },
      "include": [
        "src/**/*",
        "types/*.d.ts",
      ],
      "sourceRoot": "src"
    }
```

and to zoom in on the problem, `console.log(fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, '../../tsconfig.json')).toString().slice(212, 250))` produces:

```
       },
        "plugins": [
          { "transf
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, can you get the contents with `fs.readFile()`?

Comment: yes, I will post that test in the op

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your tsconfig.json is probably [JSON 5](https://json5.org/). Node's JSON parser uses JSON 4.
You can

1. Use JSON 4. This means removing all comments and trailing commas from your tsconfig.json
   Or
2. Read the file content and use a JSON 5 parser. I recommend using https://www.npmjs.com/package/json5

Here is a code snippet that will do what you want:

```
import json5 from "json5"
import { readFileSync } from "fs"

const tsconfig: TSCONFIG = json5.parse(readFileSync('../../tsconfig.json').toString())
```

Comment: I marked this as the answer assuming it was that, however, when I got it working (slight change to work with jest): `const tsconfig: any = json5.parse(readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, '../../tsconfig.json')).toString())
` it produces the same error as before

Comment: @robertotomás Would you mind attaching your tsconfig.json to the question ? If you still have a SyntaxError, your json is either invalid, or you are reading the wrong file (but it would be unlikely that it go to char 215)

Comment: it is in the op now

Comment: wait I see my problem, will reaward to you.. VSC has decided to automatically import readfilesync from jsonfile